# How can I measure the throughput of SQL Server Service Broker queue processor?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have a number of custom SQL Server Service Broker queues. The messages from the queues are processed by stored procedures (both T-SQL and CLR). I want to monitor the **throughput** of each processor **per queue**, i.e. how many queue messages were processed per minute in the given SSB queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one procedure per queue, take a look at `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` and note the number of executions. Take periodic snapshots diff them and that should give you what you need.

Comment: Nice idea, but one execution may process multiple queue items. Usually, the stored procedure is a loop which executes until the queue is not empty. Also, it might process items in batches. So, if SP is activated with 1000 items enqueued, it will be just 1 execution, but I want to see 1000 as my metric value.

Comment: Then modify your proc to increment a counter in a table of your own design. The idea is the same, but now you're responsible for keeping track of execution stats rather than the db engine.

Comment: That's what I was going to do, just wanted to check that I'm not missing anything native.